# What do I need to do when I include output from an ASP.NET .aspx page in a HTML page? Something like <base>

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager, radix

I have a ASP.NET file at 
http://localhost/nn/n.aspx
Output from processing that file is included in 
http://localhost/index.asp.

Is there some general or specific things I should do so that the ASP.NET code sitting on the client knows were it is?

Setting     `<form action="http://localhost/nn/n.aspx` 
makes it post to the right location, but my update-panel is failing.

I think perhaps that's the ScriptPath of the ScriptManager, and i can probably figure that out.

But I am afraid there could be other issues, and i am hoping there is something like the HTML  tag that i can use to tell my client code where it is.

Thanks
Olav

Answer (score 3):

A). What *exactly* does "..Output from processing that file is included in.." mean?

B). `<base>` tags are evil html-smells which cause more problems than they solve and are the symptom of a failed architecture

C). What do you mean by HTML page? There's no way a normal HTML page can include .aspx content, HTML is not a server side language. Certainly there are ways and means, but you need to be specific.

D). you need to give us some more idea about your code and site architecture, there's not enough info here to work this out "my update-panel is failing" is very vague indeed. *How* is it failing?

Comment: A) I do objXMLHTTP.open "GET", "http://localhost/nn/n.aspx" and then Response.Write(objXMLHTTP.responseText ) in the index.asp above.
B) Its and classic ASP page (The index.asp in the question text)

Comment: D) I am hoping for general advice or experience.  Anyway there is an error message from the Scriptmanager (Its not in English), and it is likely that that has to do with paths of files.

What I try to do is a bit like an .aspx file in an iframe or HTML object, but we dont want those constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to create a server-side control?  You don't include "output from processing" one ASPX file in another one. Instead, you create an ASCX file - a server side control and then incorporate *that* in the target ASPX file.

It is easy to do and may well be what you are looking for.  However, your question is quite ambiguous so I cannot tell for sure!

Comment: It is pretty ambiguous - sometimes new developers are just way, way off in their perception of how things work. This can lead them  to pursue "solutions" that just don't make sense to others.  I don't know if Olav is new or if we're just dealing with a language barrier.

Comment: no the host file is not an .aspx file (This should really be obvious from the question!).  I would do that if it was an .aspx file.
Anyway - I think there are mechanisms for translating paths inside controls, since "it" doesn't know where "it" will be on the server.